# What strategies are there for analysing omissions in historical sources?

Tags: historiography, sources

Individual historical texts record only a fraction of what actually happens, and critical readers may recognize incomplete explanations. Depending on what they know about the author and their interests, omissions could appear to be systematic, negligent, malicious, inadvertent, flattering, or who knows what else. Asking about what an author didn't write may be counterfactual, but can be illuminating.

Is there any historiographical or textual analytic framework that supports the analysis of authors' omissions? Two topics related at arm's length are [redaction criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redaction_criticism) and [reporting bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reporting_bias).

Comment: This seems to be requesting an analysis of all missing data over the entirety of human history; for all possible causes. Please narrow down to a more reasonable scope.

Comment: No, it  seems to be asking what work might exist on mechanisms for that analysis, not for the analysis itself.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens did you even read the question before downvoting?

Comment: @AaronBrick: Did you even consider narrowing the scope of the question before pinging me? Did you consider that perhaps I am not a down-voter?

Comment: For starters, Q requests coverage that would include:
1) Handling of unreleased WW2 classified memos;
2) Destruction of ancient texts in the fire at Alexandria library;
3) Incompleteness of Sumerian clay cuneiform tablets; and possibly
4) Gaps in archaeological record of pre-literate Scandinavian & German tribes.

Comment: I think I see our misunderstanding. I want to know about topical omissions in specific texts, not what is missing from libraries. Edited accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure this is narrow enough for SE apart from saying that the more sources the better the picture. There's also something to be said about a source writing stuff (or not) without necessarily touching this or that specific topic, all while revealing things about customs of the time and what went on in the mind of contemporaries - because to the author it appears to be a matter of course or a matter of debate. If memory serves there are quite a few examples of this in early Medieval texts. For instance Augustine of Hippo or Gregory of Tours. Chris Wickham has a few good chapters on this.